# Extract vector of numbers from a string-vector

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to python. I have a column of data with numbers and text e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
mycolumn=pd.Series(["I w0n 1200$ in poker and got 1050$ on my b111rthday",
                       "another month was b4d, I only earned 150$",
                       "d4d gave 2200, lost 0420$ in poker in 10570 Berlin"])
```

I want to take out all values above 1000 such that:

```
result=pd.Series([[1200,1050],[],[2200,10570]])
```

The result doesn't need to be pandas Series. Any other format, where I can later use empty cells or smth to subset the rest of my data, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.findall` with `(\d{4,})`, where `4` signifies atleast 4 positions, i.e > 1000

```
In [876]: mycolumn.str.findall('(\d{4,})')
Out[876]:
0           [1200, 1050]
1                     []
2    [2200, 0420, 56454]
dtype: object
```

And, as [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838429/extract-vector-of-numbers-from-a-string-vector#comment78634548_45838595), if you don't want numbers starting with `0` use

```
In [877]: mycolumn.str.findall('([1-9]\d{3,})')
Out[877]:
0     [1200, 1050]
1               []
2    [2200, 56454]
dtype: object
```

Details

```
In [878]: mycolumn
Out[878]:
0    I w0n 1200$ in poker and got 1050$ on my b111r...
1            another month was b4d, I only earned 150$
2        d4d gave 2200, lost 0420$ with 56454 in poker
dtype: object
```

Comment: `\d{4,}` but yes.

Comment: This will also match eg `0999`, although maybe this isn't an anticipated value.

Comment: You can keep to the regex and do `[1-9]\d{3,}`, I believe.